# Get last 5 users data by desc

Tags: php, mysql

```
<? 
require('../../members/inc/config.php');
require('../../lib/framework.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM members ";

 $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
 $query->execute();
 $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
?>

 <table class="table">
   <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Email</th>

   </tr>
   <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
   echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['memberID'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['username'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['email'];
     echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 ?>
 </table>
```

I guys, I want get the latest 5 users of my table. I already tried do this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT5";
```

But.. don't retrieve any results..

Comment: Is `LIMIT5` your actual code? If so, space it out `LIMIT 5`

Comment: The same, do not return any results..

Comment: Which is why I always like to ask questions first, before posting an answer ;-)

Comment: My old problem @Fred-ii-...

Comment: @RodrigoPacheco Even without the LIMIT, you get no results at all?

Comment: You can't get errors with your code, there is no error reporting enabled at all.

Comment: Only a blank page. *Hm...*, I'm wondering if `<?` has anything to do with this. If you don't have short tags enabled, then you need to change those `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ` i already put this. And @Fred-ii- I remove the `LIMIT 5` and i dont retrieve any values.. :ss

Comment: Did you read [this comment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974717/get-last-5-users-data-by-desc#comment44342254_27974717)

Comment: Yes, only appear the table titles "ID" "Member id" "Username" :ss

Comment: I am curious. Is the file you're trying to run in fact a `.php` extension?

Comment: Ofc ahah u have teamviewer? :ss

Comment: No I don't, why? and was it because of that, of what I said about the file extension?

Comment: It was the easiest way to be able to we "communicate"

Answer (score 2):

The query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Whitespace is required between LIMIT and 5

Comment: Then you should enable error reporting and tell us the errors you are getting! @RodrigoPacheco

Answer (score 0):

If you want last 5 order should be by id/creation_time

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: The OP doesn't even get any results; so this won't make it work any better. OP is getting a blank page.

Comment: Well error is not in the query, look somewhere else